# How to add nested structs to vector

Tags: c++, vector, struct, nested

I am learning C++ and I have to create a program that keeps track of vehicles and its drivers. I am using structs and vectors to achieve that. Here's the declaration of structs and vector:

```
struct Vehicle {
    string License;
    string Place;
    int Capacity;
    struct Driver {
        string Name;
        int Code;
        int Id;
    };
};


vector<Vehicle> &vtnewV
```

Ok, the program then asks for user input to get basic information, I use the following function:

```
void AddVehicle() {
    Vehicle newV;
    cout << "Enter license plate number: " << endl;
    cin >> newV.License;
    cout << "Enter the vehicle's ubication: " << endl;
    cin >> newV.Place;
    cout << "Enter the vehicle's capacity: " << endl;
    cin >> newV.Capacity;
    vtnewV.push_back(newV);
```

Then I need to ask for input to get info about the driver. I don't know how to do it. Here's what I managed to program so far:

```
void AddDriver(){
    int Plate;
    string DriverName;
    int Code;
    int Id;
    system("CLS");
    cout << "Enter the vehicle's license plate number: " << endl;
    cin >> Plate;
    if(std::find(vtnewV.begin(), vtnewV.end(), Plate) != vtnewV.end())
        system("CLS");
        cout << "Enter the driver's name: " << endl;
        cin >> DriverName;
        cout << "Enter the driver's code: " << endl;
        cin >> Code;
        cout << "Enter the driver's id: " << endl;
        cin >> Id;
        Vehicle::Driver fella;
        fella.Name = DriverName;
        fella.Code = Code;
        fella.Id = Id;

}
```

Thing is, i don't know how to "select" the struct it finds and then add the Driver struct to the Vehicle. Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT: Some users have found simmilarities between this question and other by another user. We are actually working together.

Comment: Hm. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32366226/how-to-modify-a-nested-struct-on-a-vector

Comment: We are working on it together, actually, lol

Comment: You need to create a member variable of type `Driver` in your `Vehicle`.

Comment: ok, but what I really need is to add the driver to the vehicle struct that the `std::find` finds

Comment: nice, keep creating the same thread over and over again, soon you have a mmorpg

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a member variable of type Driver in your Vehicle.

For example:

```
struct Vehicle {

    // This is just a type, not an object
    struct Driver {
        string Name;
        int Code;
        int Id;
    };

    string License; // This is an object of type std::string
    string Place;
    int Capacity; // This is an object of type int

    Driver driver; // THIS is an object of type Driver
};

int main()
{
    Vehicle vehicle;

    // now we can refer to the object of type Driver
    // that we appropriately named "driver"
    vehicle.driver.Name = "Bob"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a member of type `Driver` to your struct

```
struct Vehicle {
    string License;
    string Place;
    int    Capacity;

    struct Driver {
        string Name;
        int    Code;
        int    Id;
    } driver;    // driver is a member of Vehicle and of type Driver
};
```